# The type initializer for 'NameSpace.Settings' threw an exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception

I've a very simple class that I've added method `GetConnectionString()`. After adding it whenever any value is accesses from the Settings class it throws an exception `The type initializer for 'NameSpace.Settings' threw an exception.` As soon as I remove GetConnectionString() program works fine.

```
using System.Data.EntityClient;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CRM {
static class  Settings {
    public static bool userAuthenticated = false;

    public static string userGroup = "";
    public static Klienci currentlySelectedClient;
    public static string sqlDataConnectionDetailsCRM = GetConnectionString();

    public static string GetConnectionString() {
        string connection = "";

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = dbInitialCatalog;
        sqlBuilder.DataSource = dbServer;
        sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        sqlBuilder.UserID = dbUserName;
        sqlBuilder.Password = dbPasswWord;
        sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;

        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entity = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        entity.Metadata = @"res://*/Data.System.csdl|res://*/Data.System.ssdl|res://*/Data.System.msl";
        entity.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        entity.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

        connection = entity.ToString();

        return connection;
    }
}
```

}

If I comment out sqlBuilder and entity. It works fine..

```
    public static string GetConnectionString() {
        string connection = "";

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        //sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = dbInitialCatalog;
        //sqlBuilder.DataSource = dbServer;
        //sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        //sqlBuilder.UserID = dbUserName;
        //sqlBuilder.Password = dbPasswWord;
        //sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;

        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entity = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        //entity.Metadata = @"res://*/Data.System.csdl|res://*/Data.System.ssdl|res://*/Data.System.msl";
        //entity.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        //entity.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

        connection = entity.ToString();

        return connection;
    }
```

What's going on? It seems fine to me..

Edit:

InnerException:

> exception = "System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be
>   null.\r\nParameter name: Initial Catalog\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_InitialCatalog(String
>   value)\r\n   at CRM.Settings.GetConnectionString() in
>   C:\Projects\Project.C.S...

While `public static string dbInitialCatalog = "BazaCRM";` is set in Settings class.

Comment: Is there any useful data in the InnerException?

Comment: Added inner exception in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the fields being initialized is not guaranteed. What's going on here is that the `sqlDataConnectionDetailsCRM` is being initialized before the `dbInitialCatalog` field.

If you change those other static fields to be `const` it should fix it.

Or a better way might be to just removed your public static field, and retrieve the connection string from the method, or you might also like to investigate the [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) class, and use that to build the connection string the first time it's needed.

Comment: Turning variables into const works fine. I'll try to reorder the static fields too (since I have sqlDataConnectionDetailsCRM before dbInitialCatalog). Thanks for clarification. Wouldn't suspect order would mean anything here :-)

Comment: Don't rely on reordering fields. Although it [will work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx) someone might come and refactor your class and not realise its importance.

Answer (score 2):

According to your error the value of `dbInitialCatalog` seems to be null, so the connection string builder is throwing an error. Because this is inside the static constructor of a class, the type itself can't be loaded and the whole thing fails.

Have you tried manually supplying the connection string yourself?